# Which IP address should server listen?

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, ip

I'm writing mail server, and want send mail to my server. My server application listened in 25 port, but i don't know in which address should it listen.

```
try
{
    listener = new Listener(Address, Port);
    listener.Start();
}
```

If i send to my new mail (with my new domain), how can server listen it? Or if i use 127.0.0.1 address in server, how client can find server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen on an which is visible to the machine sending the mail.

127.0.0.1 is used for the loopback interface, so listening on it will only allow you to receive mail from the server itself.

You can listen on 0.0.0.0 to cover all your network interfaces.

Comment: Thank you, and how can i send for example to myname@mynewdomain.am         SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("myname@mydomain.am", 25);   ......                         slient.send(msg);                                                                     how can i force it work?